# Any way to shorten down a scoped slot from template to a component with props?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using named and scoped slots in a component.

The following is working flawlessly:

```
<template #name="s">
    <table-cell :value="s.item.name" />
</template>
```

But I was hoping something like this would work as well:

```
<table-cell #name="s" :value="s.item.name" />
```

It gives me no compile errors, but it doesn't render either. Runtime throws an error "s" is not defined.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more a limitation with `v-bind`.

Vue is evaluating the `:value` bound attribute not at the slot scope but at the parent level. That's why you get the *"s is not defined"* error.

For scoped slots to work, they first need to establish their scope via DOM hierarchy and you're not giving it that chance.

In short, you'll have to stick with

```html
<template #name="s">
 <!-- ... -->
</template>
```

Comment: You can see why `s` falls in the parent scope my inspecting the compiled render function. I included the compiled functions in my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You really went the extra mile on that. Wish I could upvote twice

Answer (score 1):

Attributes live in the parent function scope, but children of a scoped slot are passed the arguments in a new function scope. I didn't know the answer but was curious too and so tried out Vue's [template compilation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation) to understand.

Template:

```js
<table-row>
  <table-cell #name="s" :value="s.item.name">{{ s.item.name }}</table-cell>
</table-row>
```

Compiled render function:

```js
function anonymous() {
  with (this) {
    return _c(
      "table-row",
      [
        _c("table-cell", {
          attrs: { value: s.item.name }, // attributes use parent scoope
          scopedSlots: _u([
            {
              key: "name",
              fn: function (s) {         // children get the new function scope
                return [_v(_s(s.item.name))];
              },
            },
          ]),
        }),
      ],
      1
    );
  }
}
```

If you go with the template wrapped in a `<template>`:

```js
<table-row>
  <template #name="s">
    <table-cell :value="s.item.name">{{ s.item.name }}</table-cell>
  </template>
</table-row>
```

Compiled render function:

```js
function anonymous() {
  with (this) {
    return _c("table-row", {
      scopedSlots: _u([
        {
          key: "name",
          fn: function (s) {
            return [
              // entire table-cell is rendered inside slot scope
              _c("table-cell", { attrs: { value: s.item.name } }, [
                _v(_s(s.item.name)),
              ]),
            ];
          },
        },
      ]),
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: My new question after investigating is: why does the first example work at all? The `scopedSlots` is being passed to the child but somehow end up as the parent's scoped slot. This works because of some fancy footwork in Vue's [normalize-scoped-slots.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0baa129d4cad44cf1847b0eaf07e95d4c71ab494/src/core/vdom/helpers/normalize-scoped-slots.js)